# How do I prove $d(dx^{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx^{i_p}) = 0$?

Tags: differential-geometry

How do I prove $d(dx^{i_1} \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^{i_p}) = 0$?

Edit:

The point of the exercise is that I prove $d(\omega\wedge \eta) = d\omega\wedge \eta +(-1)^{|\omega|} \omega\wedge d\eta$. For this I need the above relation. I can only use 
a)linearity $d(\alpha + \beta) = d\alpha + d\beta$, 
b) nilpotency $d^2 = 0$ and 
c) $d(f \omega) = df \wedge \omega + f d\omega$, $df = \partial f / \partial x^j dx^j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have available the Leibniz rule, you can do this using the definition of $d$ and induction. Namely, we know that $ddx^i = 0$. Now consider, to exemplify, the form $dx^i\wedge dx^j$. Using the fact that the Leibniz rule holds for $1$-forms against arbitrary forms, you get that

$$d(x^i dx^j) =dx^i\wedge dx^j + x^i ddx^j= dx^i\wedge dx^j $$

This means that $dx^i\wedge dx^j$ is exact, so it has $0$ derivative. You can now do the above inductively: if $\omega = dx^{i_2}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{i_n}$ then 
 $$d(x^{i_1} \omega) =dx^{i_1}\wedge \omega + x^{i_1} d\omega= dx^{i_1}\wedge \omega $$
so $dx^{i_1}\wedge \omega$ is exact because $d\omega=0$ by induction.

Comment: The point of the exercise is that I prove $d(\omega\wedge \eta) = d\omega\wedge \eta +(-1)^{|\omega|} \omega\wedge d\eta$. For this I need the above relation. I can only use linearity $d(\alpha + \beta) = d\alpha + d\beta$, nilpotency $d^2 = 0$ and $d(f \omega) = df \wedge \omega + f d\omega$.

Comment: @jo_elk How have you defined the derivative on forms?

Comment: @jo_elk OK, see the updated answer. :)

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Leibniz law $d(\alpha\wedge\beta)=d\alpha\wedge\beta+(-1)^{\lvert\alpha\rvert}\alpha\wedge d\beta:$

$d(dx^{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx^{i_p}) \\= (d^2x^{i_1}\wedge\dotsb\wedge dx^{i_p} ) - (dx^{i_1}\wedge d^2x^{i_2}\wedge\dotsb\wedge dx^{i_p})+\dotsb \pm (dx^{i_1}\wedge dx^{i_2}\wedge\dotsb\wedge d^2x^{i_p})=0$

Comment: I want to prove the Leibniz law using the relation you proved. So I need it the other way around.